# Issue with creating excel workbook in java

Tags: java

I am trying to create an excel workbook in java using the JXL api.

Am using the below code and the workbook gets created but on opening it the error ""Excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid"" always pops up. Am working on it for the first time so it might be some simple error on my part. Appreciate your help. Thanks.

```
WritableWorkbook wb = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("C:\\checkexcel.xlsx"));
        WritableSheet ws = wb.createSheet("Test", 0);
        wb.write();
        wb.close();
```

Comment: JXL generates old .xls files. Not .xlsx files. If you want xlsx files, you can use Apache POI.

Comment: I had tried .xls as well but the same error persists. A solution for .xls is also fine by me. :)

Comment: Works fine here, but I'm non macOS and opening it with LibreOffice. Are you sure your version of Excel has been configured to be able to open .xls files?

Comment: Thanks. Not sure what the issue was. Its working fine after I added some data into the sheet.